# Unable to record using HTTP recording controller behind a proxy

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, action-recording, proxy

I am accessing some external sites using company proxy server.

In order to record this using Jmeter, I have to change proxy settings to local host.

Due to this, I am unable to record those sites with Jmeter.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You point jMeter proxy settings to your company proxy and your browser proxy to the local jMeter instance.

Gets you a flow like: Browser -> jMeter -> Company Proxy -> Internet

> If you are testing from behind a firewall/proxy server, you may need
>   to provide JMeter with the firewall/proxy server hostname and port
>   number. To do so, run the jmeter[.bat] file from a command line with
>   the following parameters:
>
> `jmeter -E https -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost`
>
> Read more at https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669947/how-to-set-proxy-for-jmeter-from-behind-another-proxy

Answer (score 0):

*Niels van Reijmersdal* has already given a very good suggestion.

Apart from that if you wish to record the requests you make via your browser, a good option is to use ***Blazemeter*** (It is an *extension* of *Google Chrome* browser).

With Blazemeter you can record all the websites/links you surf in your chrome browser. Each *HTTP(S)* request made from your browser and your actions performed are recorded in a test plan.

You can save this test plan and also download it as a ***JMX*** file (this is the file format of a ***Jmeter Test Plan***).

You can then open this JMX file in Jmeter to edit and also run your tests.